# Is using assertions to validate function parameters a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, anti-patterns

I am looking to validate that the parameters I am getting are what is valid given a set of circumstances. Particularly with generating SQL, I want to validate that an object passed to a function is in sync, or is valid, with the server side.

The most natural way I want to approach this is using the following

```
var InvalidIdValue = (actual) => return new Error(`Id: ${actual} is invalid. Expected id >= 1`)
var InvalidIdType = (actual, expectedType) => return new Error(`Id: ${typeof actual} is invalid. Expected ${typeof expectedType}`)

function sync(query, obj) {
    if(typeof obj.id != typeof 1) 
        return InvalidIdValue(obj.id)
    if(obj.id < 1)
        return InvalidIdValue(obj.id, 1)
    // Pull the data from server
}
```

But using assertions, I can shorten this to

```
var assert = require('assert')

function sync(query, obj) {
    assert.ok(typeof obj == typeof 1 && obj.id > 0, 'Id needs to be an integer larger than 0')
    // Pull the data from the server
}
```

I don't mind either route, but is it a bad practice to do this? My reason for the question is because I have it in my mind that assertions are intended for TDD only.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're ok with having assert as a dependency, theres nothing wrong with using assert. The code that is run from `.ok` is one line that checks if a truthy value is provided. If falsy, it calls `.fail`, which throws an error with relevent, loggable information.

EDIT:

Here are the functions `.ok` & `.fail` from the source code:

```
function fail(actual, expected, message, operator, stackStartFunction) {
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
    message: message,
    actual: actual,
    expected: expected,
    operator: operator,
    stackStartFunction: stackStartFunction
  });
}

// EXTENSION! allows for well behaved errors defined elsewhere.
assert.fail = fail;

// 4. Pure assertion tests whether a value is truthy, as determined
// by !!guard.
// assert.ok(guard, message_opt);
// This statement is equivalent to assert.equal(true, !!guard,
// message_opt);. To test strictly for the value true, use
// assert.strictEqual(true, guard, message_opt);.

function ok(value, message) {
  if (!value) fail(value, true, message, '==', assert.ok);
}
assert.ok = ok;
```

Comment: .ok appears to also throw an error with relevant and loggable information. Is there a particular use case between .ok and .fail?

Comment: `.ok` uses `.fail` internally to throw the error, I'll post the two functions as an edit to my answer.

Comment: Oh, noice. Haha, thank you very much. I didn't know if they were both written from scratch or not